# WinForm app changes form appearance after COM call to MS Word when running under Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a mixed mode win form app that does numerical analysis and then creates a report using COM automation on MS Word.

The app has a status window that shows the progress of the analysis. After the COM automation finishes creating the word DOCX report the app's appearance changes when running on Windows 8.1. There is no change on Windows 7.
The situation occurs if the winform app is x86 or x64.
The version of MS Word is 2007 x86 version.

**Here's the original look of the form:**
http://codeinsight.com/Pub/G31_Win8_Before.jpg

**After running the app and the report is created it looks like this:**
http://codeinsight.com/Pub/G31_Win8_After.jpg

The window shrinks and some fonts shrink too.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what is happening? And why it happens on Win81 and not on Win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on Word shortcut on the desktop (or on programmes), Select "Properties" and display "Compatibility" tab.

There is a checkBox "execute with a 640x480 resolution".
If it is checked, uncheck it.

If other options are checked, uncheck all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint from Graffito's answer I was able to resolve the issue. I checked the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".

[image: File Properties]